# 3 Divs equal width centered within Div (Clean without Floats)

Tags: html, css

I know this can be achieved with floats pretty easily, but I'm trying to move away from that practice. How might I achieve equal results using `display: inline-block;` rather than floats?

Here is some code with `inline-block`:
https://jsfiddle.net/hg7wx64k/

Here is some code with `floats`:
https://jsfiddle.net/hg7wx64k/

```css
#content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

#box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box3 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container" class="container">
  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the 3 boxes I'd like to have equal margins on both sides. I've thought of just manually setting the margins, but didn't know if this would be the cleanest solution. There's a lot I can do, but I'm trying to be more clean with my work. As well, this project I will not be using Bootstrap's grid system in so please no recommendations on that.

Just looking for what you guys would consider the most organized and functional method.

[image]

Comment: @dippas how it's a duplicate ? The asker already did this, he have the 3 Divs side by side[Using inline-block of float], he want to have a way to control the spacing .. maybe there is another duplicate but this one is not suitable

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=3+Divs+centered+in+div+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @dippas sorry but the question it's not about centring 3 divs ...

Comment: I'd argue this  is more of a "Here's 3 ways I could do this, what is best practice?" question more-so than a "How do I do this?" question.

Comment: Of course it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to consider `inline-block` no need to specify margin. You simply need to set the width and center the elements.

```css
#content-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:0;
}
#content-container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  font-size:initial;
  animation:anime 2s infinite linear alternate;
}


#box1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@keyframes anime {
  from {
    width:30%;
  }
  to {
    width:20%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="content-container" class="container">
  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you want to control the margin and the width to be set automatically, consider using flexbox like this:

```css
#content-container {
  padding: 0 50px; /*To control the space*/
  display: flex;
  animation: anime 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

#content-container>div {
  flex: 1; /*Make the 3 divs the same width and fill the space*/
  text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@keyframes anime {
  from {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container" class="container">
  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the answer I was looking for. Trying to better understand the shoulds and shouldn'ts as I look back on some previous dirty dirty work. I applied this to current project achieving exactly what I'm looking for with much less code, and moving on to better understand flexbox from here.

Answer (score -1):

Use display flex on the container. It's the modern way to align things.

[Read more on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

 #box1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: orange;
}

 #box2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}

 #box3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
      <div id="content-container" class="container">
        <div id="box1">
        <h1>Box 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
          <h1>Box 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
          <h1>Box 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This a simple automatic answer "use flexbox, it's better" .. but how this answer his question? did you read what he want ?

Comment: He's looking for a clean way to do things. Isn't this responding to that ?

Comment: no, read the question again ...

Comment: Thank you for including a resource for me to read up on, flex is indeed what I'm looking for and seems to be the popular opinion in modern design, so I'm going to start studying up.

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck :)